# Is the definition of a word also a synonym of that word?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

When writing, you can substitute the definition of a word for a word and still make a correct (if more complicated) sentence. Does that make the definition of a word a synonym for the actual word itself?

By the same logic, are words basically variables in a mathematical equation? Is:

3 + Y = 4

Y = 1

The same as saying:

I saw a duck today!

duck = a waterbird with a broad blunt bill, short legs, webbed feet, and a waddling gait.

If that's the case, could you therefore expand a sentence infinitely since each word has a definition that is made of words which themselves have definitions?

Comment: A ***synonym***: is ***a word*** having the same or nearly the same meaning as another in the language, as happy, joyful, elated. A ***definition*** is ***the formal statement*** of the meaning or significance of a word, phrase, idiom, etc., as found in dictionaries.

Comment: Rather, a synonym is a word having the same or nearly the same meaning as another in the language in at least one of its senses. Even one word (eg 'worm') can have non-overlapping senses, and non-identical overlapping senses ('hurricane' may be used with a strict or looser definition; [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hurricane) senses 1 and 1.1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it promotes confusion by suggesting an isomorphism between meanings of words and values of mathematical unknowns. Words are infinitely polysemic and extremely rarely identical in their distribution, whereas an unknown usually has a small and determinable set of possible values.

Comment: Yes, you could, but it would be very annoying to your readers. It is not a writer's job to serve as a real-time, inline dictionary.  If you are using many technical terms that a reader might not understand, include their definitions in a _glossary_.

Answer (score 1):

That would be more of an **appositive** than a synonym.

> **Apposition** is a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side, with one element serving to identify the other in a different way. The two elements are said to be in **apposition**. One of the elements is called the **appositive**, although its identification requires consideration of how the elements are used in a sentence.

Therefore, in the sentence `I saw a duck, a waterbird with a broad blunt bill, short legs, webbed feet, and a waddling gait.`, the definition is in apposition with the word *duck*.

Comment: But OP wanted to use the definition as a _replacement for_, not an _addition to_, the word itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Footnote:**

Very rarely, the definition will be a single word; and then it becomes a synonym.

> Today I saw a **spadger** playing snow-angels in the seed-bed.
>   Today
>   I saw a sparrow playing snow-angels in the seed-bed.
>
> Wild **mallard** came into the lake in the evening.
>   Wild ducks came into the lake in the evening.

wild duck(noun)
an undomesticated duck (especially a mallard) [[synonyms.net][1](http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/wild+duck)

Definition of synonym in English:[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synonym)

> *noun*
>   1A word or phrase that means exactly **or nearly** the same as another word or phrase in the same language, for example shut is a synonym of close:

Comment: 'Mallard' is a hyponym of 'duck'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes. though in quick crosswords, and in several online dictionaries they would pass as homonyms.  And round here, unless the variety was named (Mandarin, Pochard, Khaki Campbell) duck would mean precisely mallard.

Comment: 'Mallard (4)' is not a definition of _duck_ . Please could you show an online dictionary giving an unmodified 'duck' as a 'definition' of mallard, or an unqualified 'mallard' as a definition of 'duck'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I concede; Several online dictionaries is certainly not true. The nearest I can get is:::: Mallard is a synonym of  'wild duck'; so 'Wild duck' comes close to being a definition of wild mallard.